# Unable to login asp.net

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net

I have a code for login but it didn't work and gave an error 
**Invalid object name 'UserInformation'** on da.Fill(dt);

```
SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["mHealthDB"].ConnectionString);
    con.Open();
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select * from UserInformation where UserName =@username and Password=@password", con);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@username", TxtUsername.Text);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@password", TxtPassword.Text);
    SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    da.Fill(dt);
    if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
    {
        Response.Redirect("ExerciseList.aspx");
    }
    else
    {
        ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(Page.GetType(), "validation", "<script language='javascript'>alert('Invalid Username and Password')</script>");
    }
```

May i know What is the cause of the error and how to solve it ? Thanks

Comment: Apparently the table `UserInformation` does not exist using your configured connection string.

Comment: The error is clear, Make sure `UserInformation` table is in your Db

Comment: By the way, that "password" isn't stored in clear text, I hope? That is a security violation waiting to happen.

Comment: Make sure that you connect to the correct database schema, and that the table UserInformation exists in that schema.

Comment: @Aria problem solved :) Thanks for the solution

Comment: @HansKestingproblem solved :)

Comment: Must watch: [How not to store passowrds.](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8ZtInClXe1Q) Must read: [Salted Password Hashing - Doing it Right.](https://crackstation.net/hashing-security.htm)